# How do i get the path of File.Create("Score.txt") in C#

Tags: c#, console-application

Im trying to store score input as text file (.txt) and use it later. I created the file with File.Create() and I want to add text using `StreamWriter` but i don't know how to get the path of the file I created with `File.Create().`

PS: i don't want to specify a path because it will be used by other people not only me so i created .txt file where my console app is being executed

i tried :

```
File.Create("lHe.txt");
using(StreamWriter sww= File.AppendText("lHe.txt"))            
{
    sww.WriteLine("+112");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() as below:

```
string filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "lHe.txt");
File.Create(filePath);
using(StreamWriter sww= File.AppendText(filePath))            
{
    sww.WriteLine("+112");
}
```

Comment: FYI, This will return the current directory from where the process was launched, but not necessarily where the .exe is located.

Comment: I know that, but the question was about directory, where file will be created. File.Create() uses Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() in case that the passed file name doesn't contain path.

Comment: Good point! I realize now the duplicate is probably not correct and will remove it when I can. +1 for you